Intermittent FormatException when fetching data using Dio in Flutter
I am encountering an intermittent FormatException with the message "Unexpected end of input" when fetching data from an API using the Dio library in a Flutter application. This exception does not occur consistently; sometimes I get the correct data, and other times this error occurs.
DioException (DioException [unknown]: null
Error: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 3247)
...2024-05-06T15:00:41.000000Z","updated_at":"2024-05-07T08:51:56.000000Z"}}}]

here is my repository
  Future<ApiResult<AppointmentsResponse>> getAppointments() async {
final dio = Dio();

dio.interceptors.add(LogInterceptor(responseBody: true));
dio.interceptors.add(LogInterceptor(requestBody: true));

try {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final String? stored_token = await prefs.getString('token');
  final int? tech_id = await prefs.getInt('tech_id');

  final dio = DioFactory.getDio();

  final response = await dio.get(
      '$baseurl/api/appointments/tech/$tech_id/all',
      options: Options(
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $stored_token'},
      ));

  debugPrint("Raw API Response: $response");

  debugPrint('Response: ${response.statusCode}');
  debugPrint("response11: ${response.data}");

  // Process your response data here
  Map<String, dynamic> responseData = response.data is Map<String, dynamic>
      ? response.data
      : jsonDecode(response.data);
  return ApiResult.success(AppointmentsResponse.fromJson(responseData));
} catch (e, stacktrace) {
  logger.e("Error: $e, StackTrace: $stacktrace");
  return ApiResult.failure(e.toString());
}

}
I also have this in my bloc provider
 BlocProvider<AppointmentCubit>(
        create: (BuildContext context) => AppointmentCubit(AppointmentRepo(
            apiService: ApiService(Dio(BaseOptions(
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
          },
          followRedirects: false,
          // // will not throw errors
          validateStatus: (status) => true,
        ))))),
      ),


I think it's something in your fromJson method. Double check it how it's parsing the received Json. Add breakpoints to help that

but in my code there is no issue right !!

so after seeing our i have a suggestion u should use this.
Future<ApiResult<AppointmentsResponse>> getAppointments() async {
final dio = Dio();

dio.interceptors.add(LogInterceptor(responseBody: true));
dio.interceptors.add(LogInterceptor(requestBody: true));

try {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final String? stored_token = await prefs.getString('token');
  final int? tech_id = await prefs.getInt('tech_id');

  final dio = DioFactory.getDio();

  final response = await dio.get(
      '$baseurl/api/appointments/tech/$tech_id/all',
      options: Options(
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $stored_token'},
      ));

  debugPrint("Raw API Response: $response");

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
 debugPrint('Response: ${response.statusCode}');
  debugPrint("response11: ${response.data}");
//process your respone data here 

Map <String, dynamic> responseData = responseData is Map<String,  dynamic>

? response.data : jsoneDecode(response.data);
return ApiResult.success(AppointmentsResponse.fromJson(responseData));
} else{
// handle non-200 status code
return ApiResult.failure("failed to get appointments. Status code: ${response.statusCode}");
}
} catch (e, stacktrace) {
  logger.e("Error: $e, StackTrace: $stacktrace");
  return ApiResult.failure(e.toString());
}

i add something hope this will help

responseData can't assigned can't be referenced before it is declared
